# Is CGI still slow when used with a compiled program that doesn't require a VM?

Tags: php, web-services, perl, cgi

When I learned CGI I learned that any programing language can be used to hook it's output to the http response message and it's input is the http request message. Many articles I've red talk about CGI in the context of Perl, is this because Perl is the most common language used in conjunction with CGI?

What I'm wondering is if CGI connects to a program written in C/C++ would it still be slower than using PHP?

Comment: This question is entirely too vague to be answered. Define "faster", "most common", and "slow". Compared to what? Doing what? You're asking for a discussion of C/C++ vs Perl vs PHP, and this isn't a discussion site. Please edit your question to make it more specific and less prone to opinion.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You can use Servlets with java. But it all depends what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Even if a new process has to be started for a program written in C/C++, using CGI, wouldn't that always be faster than using PHP since PHP is interpreted?

Comment: Pound for pound, it would likely be faster, but perhaps not by as much as you think for the common web request. Of course, writing in C/C++ means you lose the entire CGI stack for Perl/PHP etc. A compromise is to move lengthy calculations outside of the language (through a native function interface, e.g.), not much calculation should be done in processing the client's request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CGI is a standard denoting how an application should interact, not a specific program itself.
The reason CGI is often too slow is because it requires a process to be started for the request and closed at the end of that request.

FastCGI differs from CGI in that it allows a process to serve multiple requests (it maintains a pool of request processors). This way the lengthy process startup/shutdown can be avoided for the majority of incoming requests.

For more information on CGI and its 'successors' take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface#Drawbacks

With this in mind, the performance characteristics depend not only on the language and its implementation, but also the interface used to process requests.

It is likely for a lot of simple requests the process startup time will far outweigh the processing time, making the language X vs Y argument moot.

Comment: One should keep in mind the saying, "It's slow because it's doing a lot."  With CGI, it's usually the startup cost that is expensive, as you've mentioned, and nowadays CGI has been all but replaced by persistent processes.  Once the application is running, performance is usually fine with an interpreted language.  After layering onto C/C++ entities like hashes, abstract datastructures, reference counting, scalar types independent of lower level types, and so on, you're back to the same fat that is built into interpreted languages, but with all the unpleasantries of a lower level language.